# How can I keep the database data if the models changed

Tags: java, database, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm working on a project with Play framework it uses EBean as an ORM API and I wonder how could i preserve the old data if I needed to change the models after lauching my application to the public ?
Because after each update a new convolution is created and the data is reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ebean's plugin in Play 2.x always drops full structure and recreates it - which causes loosing the data. There's no support for updating only changed elements (at all, even in pure Ebean) [see post at their forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ebean/_TA5OOJq2oY).

Only workaround is disabling it and creating next evolutions (2.sql, 3.sql, etc) manually and placing in them only changed/added tables and columns. Then in file 1.sql file delete two first lines (which tell's that it was created with plugin) - in such case it will no try to generate whole DDL again instead it will look for your manual evolutions.

Optionally you can use your favorit GUI to manage DB's changes, sometimes it's just faster.

To disable Ebean plugin totally add (or uncomment) this line in your `application.conf`:

```
evolutionplugin=disabled
```